# How to check the correct execution of the calling to a page using JQuery and XAMPP?

Tags: php, jquery, xampp, webserver

I state that I'm very inexperienced with web programming. 
I'm trying to write a very simple web server in which suppliers must login to have access to a page that presents a table. In the table there are all the active orders for that supplier. Every row presents a list of fields: most of them are only readable, but the last three are also editable. The request I have to satisfy is that every time a supplier leaves an editable field, an update query runs to the database to update that field. I know, it's inefficient, but this is the request I've received.
My problem is that I've all already ready: the pages, the methods to generate the queries, etc...

...but when the page launches che ajax request to the saving page, nothing happens.
I've tried everything, I also tried to execute some very stupids examples find out on sites like w3school and other. Also the most stupid jquery function that try to call another page doesn't run, and I don't know why.

My questions are two:

- is the below code right? I think it is, I'm not able to find out any error, but i'm not sure at this point.
- the second one, is there a way to check if it is a problem of the pc, of the web server, or something else that does'nt wirk properly? The machine is not mine, so I'm not authorized to try to install or uninstall to check the status of every component.

Thank you all.

Here the code of the client side page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <TITLE>Orders</TITLE>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <script>

        var temp = "";

        function saveContext(obj) {
            temp = "";
            temp = obj.value;   
        }

        function handleCheckbox(obj) {
            if (obj.value == 1)
            {
                obj.value = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                obj.value = "1";
            }
            var values = obj.id.split("//");
            updateDB("UPDATE ordini SET " + values[3] + "=\"" + obj.value + "\" WHERE idFornitore=\"" + values[0] + "\" and idOrdine=\"" + values[1] + "\" and codiceArticolo=\"" + values[2] + "\"");

        }

        // Validates that the input string is a valid date formatted as "aaaa-mm-dd"
        function isValidDate(dateString) {
            // First check for the pattern aaaa-mm-dd
            if(!/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/.test(dateString))
                return false;

            // Parse the date parts to integers
            var parts = dateString.split("-");
            var day = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
            var month = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
            var year = parseInt(parts[0], 10);

            // Check the ranges of month and year
            if(year < 1000 || year > 3000 || month == 0 || month > 12)
                return false;

            var monthLength = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];

            // Adjust for leap years
            if(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0))
                monthLength[1] = 29;

            // Check the range of the day
            return day > 0 && day <= monthLength[month - 1];
        };

        function handleNota(obj) {
            var values = obj.id.split("//");
            updateDB("UPDATE ordini SET " + values[3] + "=\"" + obj.value + "\" WHERE idFornitore=\"" + values[0] + "\" and idOrdine=\"" + values[1] + "\" and codiceArticolo=\"" + values[2] + "\"");              
        }

        function handleData(obj) {
            var values = obj.id.split("//");
            if(isValidDate(obj.value) == true) 
            {
                updateDB("UPDATE ordini SET " + values[3] + "=\"" + obj.value + "\" WHERE idFornitore=\"" + values[0] + "\" and idOrdine=\"" + values[1] + "\" and codiceArticolo=\"" + values[2] + "\"");              
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Insert a valid date");
                document.getElementById(obj.id)
                obj.value=temp;
                obj.Focus();
            }
        }

        function updateDB(sql) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/save.php",
                data: {
                    query: sql;
                },
                success: function(output){
                    alert(output);
                },
                error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    alert('Exception: ', status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<?php include "config.php"; $temp=""; ?>   <!--  <==import code for database connection  -->

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="colonna-1"><img src="immagini/logosx.png" height="123" width="210" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div id="colonna-2" style="text-align:center">           
            <div id="contenitore">
                <div id="utente">
                    <?php
                        $user=$_SESSION['idFornitore'];              
                    ?>
                    <table id="enter">
                        <tr height="123"></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img id="user" src="immagini/user.png" height="20" width="20"></td>
                            <td align="left">     Benvenuto </td>
                            <td align="letf"><?php echo"$user"."   "?></td>
                            <td align="left"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div> <!--utente-->
                <div id="contenuto">

                    <?php

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ordini WHERE idFornitore='$user' ORDER BY idOrdine, codiceArticolo ASC";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        $numfields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

                        echo "<table id='elencoordini'><tr>";

                        for ($i=1; $i < $numfields; $i++)
                        {
                            echo '<th>'.ucwords(mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->name).'</th>';
                        }
                        echo "</tr><br><br><br><br>\n";

                        $nr = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                        if ($nr != 0){
                            for($x = 0; $x < $nr; $x++){
                                while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    for ($i=1; $i < $numfields-3; $i++)
                                    {
                                        echo '<th><input type="text" value="'.ucwords($row[$i]).'"readonly style="color:DimGrey"></th>';
                                    }           



                                    if ($row[$i] == null) 
                                    {
                                        echo '<th><input type="text" id="'.$row[0]."//".$row[1]."//".$row[3]."//".mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->name.'" value="" style="font-weight: bold;" onclick="saveContext(this)" onfocusout="handleData(this)"></th>';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '<th><input type="text" id="'.$row[0]."//".$row[1]."//".$row[3]."//".mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->name.'" value="'.ucwords($row[$i]).'" style="font-weight: bold;" onclick="saveContext(this)" onfocusout="handleData(this)"></th>';                                        
                                    }



                                    if ($row[$i+1] == 1)
                                    {
                                        echo '<th><input type="checkbox" id="'.$row[0]."//".$row[1]."//".$row[3]."//".mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i+1)->name.'" name="checkdate" value="1" checked onclick="handleCheckbox(this)"></th>';
                                    }
                                    else 
                                    {
                                        echo '<th><input type="checkbox" id="'.$row[0]."//".$row[1]."//".$row[3]."//".mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i+1)->name.'" name="checkdate" value="0" onclick="handleCheckbox(this)"></th>';
                                    }



                                    if ($row[$i+2] == null) 
                                    {
                                        echo '<th><input type="text" id="'.$row[0]."//".$row[1]."//".$row[3]."//".mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i+2)->name.'" value="" style="width: 400px; font-weight: bold;" maxlength="4000" onfocusout="handleNota(this)"></th>';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '<th><input type="text" id="'.$row[0]."//".$row[1]."//".$row[3]."//".mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i+2)->name.'" value="'.ucwords($row[$i+2]).'" style="width: 400px; font-weight: bold;" maxlength="4000" onfocusout="handleNota(this)"></th>';
                                    }
                                    echo "</tr>\n";
                                }
                            }
                            echo "</table><br><br><br><br>\n";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "No records found!";
                        }

                        // Close db conn
                        mysqli_close($conn);

                    ?>

                </div> <!--contenuto-->
            </div><!--contenitore-->
        </div><!--colonna2-->
        <div id="colonna-3">
        </div><!--colonna3-->
    </div> <!--main-->
</div> <!--wrap-->

<?php include "footer.inc.php"?>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code of the server side page that, in my intention, has to update the database:

```
<?php

include "config.php";     //import code for database connection

$query=$_POST['query'];     

if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: BTW, all the code on the client side can be viewed and manipulated. **Never send the SQL queries like this, ever**. Instead send the information and generate the queries in PHP after checking that the posted data is valid. What happens when you go to the page _/save.php_ directly?

Comment: Using a simple save.php that only has <?php echo "Hello!" ?>, then the simplest php page ever, if I access to it directly, I see Hello, if I try to call it using  ajax, nothing happens. I'm sure the problem is not in the database connection, but in the ajax call. But I can't figure out what it is

Comment: A quick tip in cases like this. You can press F12 in the browser to look console errors. Your script has an error in _updateDB()_. Remove the ";" at the end of _query: sql;_ and try to see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

In generell I would do some backtracing basically since you have the echos in your php file you should check wether or not they are in the alert window since you use an ajax post to call the file. If you receive some output in your alert window that is defined in the php file, then you know for sure that your php file is being called correctly maybe you echo out the query that is being sent sometimes an input that contains a quote -> ' can screw up the query.

So basically do some backtracing until you realize that something is not called properly and there you should find the error.

Also I strongly recommend to build a database adapter class and some controllers to handle the functionalities. Having mysql functions inside the html file is a huge no go.

Comment: I've already tried this way, using save.php as a simple       

    <?php
        echo "here";
    ?>      

but nothing happens